# New Password not Being Accepted

Tags: raspbian, password

My new password is being rejected at first use. Following previous threads I used the  init=/bin/sh to the cmdline file. On bootup I receive message "job control turned off."
The ending of the cmdline file  is different to all examples shown inas mucha s it does not end at "deadline rootwait" but ends "quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles"

Do I place the "init..." immediately after "rootwait" as placing it at the end of the present line (as shown below) results in "job control turned off"?

"console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles init=/bin/sh"

Comment: You are obviously using NOOBS - all the tutorials assume normal Raspbian.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I place the "init..." immediately after "rootwait" as placing it at the end of the present line (as shown below) results in "job control turned off"?

As far as I'm aware [the order of the parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) doesn't matter, although there could be exceptions to that.  What is important is that the file be **all one line**.

The "job control turned off" isn't because of that, it's because something is wrong with the system -- eg., the kernel can't properly access the root filesystem to load some needed module, although it clearly can in some sense since this the message is actually from `/bin/sh`, the shell.  You can read up on [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html) if you like; not having it is not a huge problem if all you have to do is set a password, but what it is symptomatic of may be a huge problem: If there is not proper read-write access to the root filesystem, setting a new password will fail one way or another.

At the prompt, try: `mount | grep mmcblk0p7`.  You should get this:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p7 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
```

The important part is the `rw` (read-write) in parentheses.  If you don't have that, the problem may be SD card corruption that could not be fixed by `fsck` (which is enabled in your cmdline.txt).